# how can i know the wiki pages that are referencing a document inside my enterprise wiki site collection

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, configuration, hyperlink, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection and I have two libraries; “Page” which contain the html wiki pages & “Documents” which contain uploaded documents.  Now on some wiki pages users upload documents inside the “Documents” library (such as word document or pdfs),  and then they reference them inside the wiki pages.

So my question is that we need to identify all the wiki pages that have links to documents , so is this possible?. Now for a wiki pages if I want to know all the wiki pages that are referencing it, I can check the “incoming links” option under “Page Option” tab,, so is there a similar option for the documents? i mean to check which wiki pages are referencing it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SPFile` object has a `ForwardLinks` and `BackwardsLink` property that contain `SPLinkCollection` that you may be able to query.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea 0;

$web = get-spweb '<url>'
$list = $web.lists['Pages'];

foreach($file in $list.items){
    $links = $file.ForwardLinks;

    foreach($link in $links){
        if($link.url -like '*/Documents/*'){
            Write-Host $file.name $link.url
        }
    }

}
```

You can also use CSOM - which doesn't appear to expose the `ForwardLinks`/`BackwardLinks` properties, but I was able to get at the HTML content of the page and could search across that as a string.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") 

$weburl = 'https://<URL>';
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl) 

$ctx.Credentials = Get-Credential;

$web = $ctx.Web;
$ctx.Load($web);

$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle('Pages');
$ctx.load($list);

#Note - you can create a specific CAML query to get specific documents as well.
$query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(10);
$items = $list.GetItems($query);
$ctx.Load($items); 

$ctx.ExecuteQuery();



foreach($fileItem in $items){
    $pageContent = $fileItem['PublishingPageContent'];
    If($pageContent | select-string -Pattern '/documents/' -SimpleMatch){
        #page has link to documents library
        Write-Host "Page has link"
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried your script but i got the following exception on the "PS H:\> $ctx.ExecuteQuery();" command :-
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "List 'Pages' does not
exist at site with URL 'http://tvstg01/kb/customerservicekb'."
At line:1 char:1
+ $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException

Comment: i used exactly the same script you provide but i changed the "$weburl = 'https://<URL>';" to match mu site collection URL.

Comment: any idean what is the problem ?

Comment: It can't find your library in that site.  Is that URL your website where the list exists or if that list itself? I may have some time this afternoon to try the alternative approach from the server.

Comment: now the $weburl should refer to the site collection url , not to the library it self is this correct ?

Comment: If you have access to the server the code I added in the update may be easier for you to use.